# python csv.read fails on second iteration

Tags: python, parsing, csv

my code looks something like this:

```
for filename in files:
  with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    values=list(csvreader)
  dosomething()
```

i have about 10 files i want to process and it works without a problem for the first file. but when python tries to start processing the second file it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "plot.py", line 20, in <module>
values=list(csvreader)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

has anybody an idea why this won't work?

Comment: I bet there is a variable called `list` somewhere in your code.

Comment: yup, that was it. for list in lists: foo()       i thought a variable defined like this is private, but then again i started coding python 3 hours ago.  thanks alot to all of you, i wish i could accept more than 1 answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhere you have used a (global, if the problem is showing up here) variable named `list` to hold an instance of a list. That is a bad idea. The name `list` is looked up every time it's used, and that variable is found in preference to the actual `list` type, which is what you want (i.e. in order to construct a list from the `csvreader` results).

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that list is being redefined somewhere outside of the code block you have provided.  For example:

```
>>> list = list()
>>> list()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Check that you have not rebound list to some other object elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

since you haven't posted your actual code, I cannot be sure, but it appears you are assigning to a var  named list during the processing of the first file, shadowing the actual built-in list function.